# Can't connect react-native app (expo) with flask server

Tags: python, react-native, flask, expo

I'm trying to connect my expo-app with the flask server

Here is the request

```
 fetch("127.0.0.1:5000/post", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                'base64' : photoData["base64"]
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log("******************\nRESULT");
            console.log(result);
            })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
```

On the server-side. I've already tried to send request using postman and everything worked.

```
@app.route('/post', methods=['Post'])
def webhook():
    file = request.args['base64']
    rv = base64.b64encode(str.encode(file))  # bytes
    rv = rv.decode('ascii')  # str
    return rv
```

Here is the error I got on expo

```
Network request failed
- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Does anyone know the solution?